# Woocommerce Product Image and Thumbnails custom function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am looking to edit the WooCommerce product images and thumbnails.

My goal is to add an attribute to the `<a>` tag.I want to add: `data-lightbox="Gallery"`, but I cannot see how can I do this.
The template files seem the obvious place but the code doesn't have the anchor code structure I was hoping for:

**woocommerce\single-product\product-image.php**

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $product;

$columns           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 4 );
$post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();
$wrapper_classes   = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_single_product_image_gallery_classes',
    array(
        'woocommerce-product-gallery',
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? 'with-images' : 'without-images' ),
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-' . absint( $columns ),
        'images',
    )
);
?>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $wrapper_classes ) ) ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
        <?php
        if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
            $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
        } else {
            $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
            $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src( 'woocommerce_single' ) ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        ?>
    </figure>
</div>
```

and the thumbnails is the same.

**woocommerce\single-product\product-thumbnails.php**

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $product;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id() ) {
    foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id ), $attachment_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
}
```

I assume I need to use filter, but I haven't used this before. Or do I remove the action for the image and thumbnails and add my own function?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

function my_plugin_show_product_image() {
// my custom image code where i can use my own attributes, div structure etc
// i have no idea what php is required to show the images
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'my_plugin_show_product_image', 20 );

function my_plugin_show_product_image() {
// my custom image code where i can use my own attributes, div structure etc
// i have no idea what php is required to show the images
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'my_plugin_show_product_image', 10 );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In short:

We are going to overwrite the default template and change the function that is being called to generate our  tag and the image inside it.
Next, we are going to create this function into our functions.php and add the attribute we want to the  tag.

---

1. copy/paste the template `woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php` to your directory: `your-child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php` so you can overwrite it's functionality
2. change `$html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );` to
   `$html = my_custom_img_function( $post_thumbnail_id, true );`
3. copy paste the following to your `functions.php`

```
/**
 * overwritten from https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_gallery_image_html/
 */
function my_custom_img_function($attachment_id, $main_image = false)
{
    $flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters('woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-slider'));
    $gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size('gallery_thumbnail');
    $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters('woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array($gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height']));
    $image_size        = apply_filters('woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size);
    $full_size         = apply_filters('woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters('woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full'));
    $thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $thumbnail_size);
    $full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $full_size);
    $alt_text          = trim(wp_strip_all_tags(get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)));
    $image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
        $attachment_id,
        $image_size,
        false,
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
            array(
                'title'                   => _wp_specialchars(get_post_field('post_title', $attachment_id), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true),
                'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars(get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment_id), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true),
                'data-src'                => esc_url($full_src[0]),
                'data-large_image'        => esc_url($full_src[0]),
                'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr($full_src[1]),
                'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr($full_src[2]),
                'class'                   => esc_attr($main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : ''),
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $image_size,
            $main_image
        )
    );

    return '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" data-thumb-alt="' . esc_attr( $alt_text ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a data-lightbox="Gallery" href="' . esc_url($full_src[0]) . '">' . $image . '</a></div>';
}
```

As you can see the only thing we added to the default function is the attribute you wanted on the last line @ return statement.